# Testing email locally on a windows machine

Tags: windows, php, email, smtp, testing

This is a question I've tried to answer for a long time now. I'm currently working on a personal project on a windows XP machine and it's come to the point where I need to send emails to test some functionality.

I'm looking for an application that I can setup that mimics an SMTP server or actually IS an SMTP server that when PHP runs the `mail()` command, this application will catch said email and store it in a way that is easily retrievable by me.

Another post on here on SF mentioned an application called Neptune, however website hosting that does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/) will run on XP and does not require a huge amount of configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Windows XP has the ability to run an SMTP server via IIS.  [This article](http://www.ehow.com/how_4489548_set-up-smtp-server-windows.html) may help in getting you setup.

Comment: +1. I second cypher's answer. The virtual SMTP server offered by IIS should be the adequate solution for your scenario. You can even setup aliases with it.

Comment: At the time I saw this reply, I had already installed and been using hMailServer. Thank you for your time though!